# How can I git subtree a subdirectory of the remote?

Tags: git, subtree

There's a remote repository with multiple subdirectories (lib/Android and lib/iOS). Is it possible for me to only subtree in lib/Android?

Comment: No. You have to clone the entire repository

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use `sparse checkout`, which was added in git 1.7.0 .

e.g:

Init repo

```
mkdir git-subdir
cd git-subdir
git init
```

Enable Sparse Checkouts

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
```

Tell Git which directories you want

```
echo "some/dir/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

Add the remote

```
git remote add -f origin https://github.com/git/git.git
```

Pull

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: what is the -f option in `git remote add`?